# Check if parameter is NULL within WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, optimization, stored-procedures, parameters

I´m having trouble with a Stored Procedure that takes about forever to execute. It is quite large and I can understand that I´ll take some time but this one continues for almost 20 minutes.

After some debugging and researching I noticed that replacing this part of the `WHERE` clause;

```
((p_DrumNo IS NULL) OR T_ORDER.ORDER_ID IN (SELECT ORDER_ID FROM ORDERDELIVERY))
```

made a HUGE difference. So the Procedure works just fine as long as p_DrumNo is NULL or I modify the above to not check if p_DrumNo is NULL;

```
(T_ORDER.ORDER_ID IN (SELECT ORDER_ID FROM ORDERDELIVERY))
```

The goal with this `WHERE` clause is to filter the result set on p_DrumNo if it´s passed in to the Stored Procedure. The `WHERE` clause then continues with further conditions but this specific one halts the query.

ORDERDELIVERY is just a ~temporary table containing ORDER_IDs related to the parameter p_DrumNo.

How can this simple IS NULL-check cause such big impact? It´s probably related to the use of `OR` together with the subquery but I don´t understand why as the subquery itself works just fine.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE** [2011-09-23 10:13]

I´ve broken down the problem into this small query that show the same behaviour;

**Example A**

SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM T_ORDER WHERE
('290427' IS NULL OR ORDER_ID IN (SELECT ORDER_ID FROM T_ORDER WHERE ORDERNO LIKE '290427%') );
```

Execution plan

```
OPERATION   OBJECT_NAME     OPTIONS     COST
------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT STATEMENT                    97
FILTER
TABLE ACCESS    T_ORDER         FULL        95
TABLE ACCESS    T_ORDER         BY INDEX ROWID  2
INDEX       PK_ORDER        UNIQUE SCAN 1
```

**Example B**

SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM T_ORDER WHERE
( ORDER_ID IN (SELECT ORDER_ID FROM T_ORDER WHERE ORDERNO LIKE '290427%') );
```

Execution plan

```
OPERATION   OBJECT_NAME     OPTIONS     COST
------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT STATEMENT                    4
NESTED LOOPS                        4
TABLE ACCESS    T_ORDER         BY INDEX ROWID  3
INDEX       IX_T_ORDER_ORDERNO  RANGE SCAN   2  
TABLE ACCESS    T_ORDER         BY INDEX ROWID  1  
INDEX       PK_ORDER        UNIQUE SCAN 0
```

As you all can see the first query (example A) makes a full table scan. Any ideas on how I can avoid this?

Comment: Can you post the full SQL statement and the query plan in both cases?  Is `OrderDelivery` a global temporary table?  Or a permanent table where the data is transient?  How selective is this predicate?

Comment: OrderDelivery is a temporary table within a cursor. I rather not include the entire procedure but I´ve updated my question with an example. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Instead of evaluating your procedure's parameter state in the SQL statement itself, move that evaulation to the containing PL/SQL block so it's executed only once before the ideal SQL statement is submitted. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_sp (p_DrumNo VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    IF p_DrumNo IS NULL THEN
        SELECT ...
        INTO ... -- Assumed
        FROM ...
        WHERE my_column = p_DrumNo;
    ELSE
        SELECT ...
        INTO ... -- Assumed
        FROM ...
        WHERE ORDER_ID IN (SELECT ORDER_ID FROM ORDERDELIVERY);
    END;
END;
```

I've also had some success in tuning SQL statements with an `OR` by breaking the statement into two mutually exclusive statements with a UNION ALL:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE p_DrumNo IS NULL
AND ORDER_ID IN (SELECT ORDER_ID FROM ORDERDELIVERY)
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE p_DrumNo IS NOT NULL
AND my_column = p_DrumNo;
```

Answer (score 3):

You came across such an issue due to the fact your index doesn't work if you include `OR` to your query. To get the same info I'd rather do this to make the index work (basing on updated query):

```
SELECT * FROM T_ORDER WHERE '290427' IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T_ORDER WHERE ORDER_ID IN (SELECT ORDER_ID FROM T_ORDER WHERE ORDERNO LIKE '290427%'));
```

It will return the same result since `290427` seem to be a variable and it tends to be null or not null at the particular moment.

But also you can try using [dynamic sql](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm) inside you stored procedure for such purposes:

```
%begin_of_the_procedure%

query_ := 'SELECT * FROM T_ORDER WHERE 1=1';
if var_ is not null then
  query_ := query_||' AND ORDER_ID IN (SELECT ORDER_ID FROM T_ORDER WHERE ORDERNO LIKE '''||to_char(var_)||'%'')';
end if;
open cursor_ query_;

%fetching cursor loop%
%end_of_the_procedure%
```

And I wanted to say that I don't see sence of that `IN`, it'd be quite the same:

```
SELECT * FROM T_ORDER WHERE ('290427' IS NULL OR ORDERNO LIKE '290427%');
```